# Recovery model of current database

Tags: db2

I want to know how can I change the recovery model of my current database. I am having sysadm rights.Operating system is windows, Db2 10.5.

can some one let me know the command please

Comment: What do you understand by recovery model? this is too broad. BTW, this question does not belong to SOF.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I want to set my recovery model to simple.According to my understanding at certain point of time database requires some recovery .This recovery can be done in simple,full,checked etc. I just want to find out my current recovery model & to change that model to simple.Kindly excuse me if i am wrong at any point. new to db2

Comment: You are confusing DB2 and SQL Server.

Comment: Simplest would be to make sure LOGARCHMETH1 is set to OFF. Then you only have circular logging and can only offline backups.

Answer (score 1):

In DB2, the SQL Server's recovery model simple equivalent is called circular.

```
<p>C:\WINDOWS\system32>db2 get db cfg for sample |findstr "LOGARCHMETH1 LOGARCHMETH2" <\p>
<p> First log archive method                 (LOGARCHMETH1) = OFF </p>
<p> Second log archive method                (LOGARCHMETH2) = OFF </p>
```

If both `logarchmeth1` and `logarchmeth2` are set to `OFF`, the database uses circular logging and is not rollforward recoverable.